# How to open a link of external website on the same iframe (embed website)?

Tags: html, iframe, target

I created an iframe to embed an external website, the problem is that, for example, if the user clicks on the Twitter button of the embed website, this action will take the user out of my page, loading Twitter's page, I want to avoid that, I want to load that content on the same iframe, how can I do that? I tried naming the iframe, the parent target, but that didn't work.
Here an example of my code:

```
<iframe src="http://superluchas.com/" width="100%" height="1000" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the third party page targets a specific frame (including `_top` and `_blank`) then there is nothing you can do to override that.

Security restrictions prevent you getting access to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The twitter button probably has '_blank' as target in `<a>` tag. You will need to change it to '_self'. More info on target attribute can be found - [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Also here is an example in which if you click the links inside of IFrame target you will see the page loads into the frame itself, not outside. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HnXFj/2/)